# cy.get('element').contains('text') is not working when I have a string that includes a negative number (e.g. cy.get('element').contains('-1'))

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, contains

I have been using cypress for a couple of months now, but I can't seem to be able to solve this problem.
I have an array of values ( var valArray=['-1', '-0.5','0', '0.5', '1'] ). And I want to check that all these values are present on a specific page loaded in cypress. I use a for cycle for this:

```
    for (var i=0; i<valArray.length; i++)
{
    cy.get('element1').find('element2').contains('text', valArray[i])   
    
}
```

My tests work just fine for all the positive values (0, 0.5, 1), but they fail for the negative ones. [Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFWRf.png) [Elements on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ6nP.png). I have been looking at other questions but I couldn't find an answer. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Using `.contains('text', valArray[i])` will look for elements that have selector `text` and value from array (see [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Selector)) If you want to check if the value is present on the page you ought use `should`:

```
cy.get('element1').find('element2').should('contain.text', valArray[i]);
```